# fatal error: gst/gst.h: No such file or directory #include <gst/gst.h>

Tags: c++, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I am trying to install [GStreamer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/index.html?gi-language=c) on windows for writing a C++ code but after installing the files

> gstreamer-1.0-devel-msvc-x86_64-1.18.3.msi

and

> gstreamer-1.0-msvc-x86_64-1.18.3.msi

from https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/windows/ and it installs correctly. But when I run the example code basic-tutorial-1.c from gst-docs repo it says

> fatal error: gst/gst.h: No such file or directory  #include
> <gst/gst.h>

I am just getting started using GStreamer so any help would be hugely appreciated! :)

This is what I did:

```
D:\gst-docs\gst-docs\examples\tutorials> gcc .\basic-tutorial-1.c 

.\basic-tutorial-1.c:1:10: fatal error: gst/gst.h: No such file or directory #include <gst/gst.h> 
^~~~~~~~~~~ compilation terminated.
```

The header file is located in the directory: `C:\gstreamer\1.0\msvc_x86_64\include\gstreamer-1.0\gst` after installing using the installer files.

Edit: I did try other guides on StackOverflow but none seem to work for me.

Comment: How did you set the `-I` compiler option when compiling the example code? Is it specifying the install directory correctly (I suppose the header file should be there after a successful installation)?

Comment: This is what I did: D:\gst-docs\gst-docs\examples\tutorials> gcc .\basic-tutorial-1.c
.\basic-tutorial-1.c:1:10: fatal error: gst/gst.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gst/gst.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

Comment: And that header file was installed where? You have to add a compiler flag `-I<dir-to-lookup-gst\gst.h>`. (the parent directory of gst).

Comment: And more problems: To compile c++ code use the command `g++` and a file extension like `.cc`, `.cpp`. `.c` implicates that c code is contained in the source file.

Comment: That file was in the gstreamer\1.0\msvc_x86_64\include\gstreamer-1.0\gst\ directory. But when I used this during compiling with -I flag. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: I meant C++ for the file I am writing and this is from the gst-docs repo. I am sorry for that confusion.

Comment: Please add all that information to your question (same way as I did for you last time). Verbatim command input and error messages. Also information of how these  directories (current, installation path, sourcefile path) are relative to each othe. Otherwise we canb provide you with guess work here only.

Comment: I have edited the question as directed.

Comment: You added only a link. Keep everything in your question selfcontained please. Links can rot, and may render your question useless for future readers.

Comment: I've added the directory where the header file can be found to the question. I am kinda new to stack overflow so sorry for that...

Comment: Sorry, you misunderstood: We of course need to know what these directories are on **your machine** actually, not what they tell in the docs (that's pretty clear to me already).

Comment: Oh, The directory for the header file `<gst/gst.h>`  on my machine is `C:\gstreamer\1.0\msvc_x86_64\include\gstreamer-1.0\gst\gst.h` I've added that to the question as well.

Comment: So the compiler flag you need to provide for the **`g++`** command is ` -I C:\gstreamer\1.0\msvc_x86_64\include\gstreamer-1.0\`.

Comment: Oh, great! That worked! Thank you! A couple of questions if that's OK: Can I pass multiple directories like this? And isn't it supposed to be added to the include path of gcc when I install GStreamer?

Comment: _"Can I pass multiple directories like this?"_ Yes. Use one flag per directory (a plain list won't work). _"And isn't it supposed to be added to the include path of gcc"_ No, not really the compilers include path. User include path maybe  (/usr/lib/opt in Unix like systems). That may vary from library to library, and usually can be configured cutomized during installation.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!